# Adding view onto an activity

Tags: android

If I want to add a button in this class so that I can call the `onclicklistener`, how should I do it?

```
public class GameView extends View {
    Path circle;
    Paint cPaint;
    Paint tPaint;
    String z;
    int i = 65, strt, arc, leftx, topy, rightx, bottomy, maxx, maxy;
    boolean flag1, flag2, flag3;
    double n1, n2;
    int n, n3 = 180,n4,n5 = 90;
    float f1 = 180, f2 = 90;
    Button b1;
    Random r = new Random();
    RectF  oval;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        leftx = 0;
        topy = 60;
        rightx = 150;
        bottomy = 120;

        z = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i));

        cPaint = new Paint();
        cPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

        strt = 45;
        arc = 315;

        n1 = Math.random() * 600;
        Log.d("random", z);

        if (flag2 == false)
            new DrawThread(this);

        // cPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        tPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        tPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
        tPaint.setTextSize(20 * scale);
    }

    public void onSizeChanged(int w,int h,int oldh,int oldw) {
        maxx = oldw;
        maxy = oldh;
    }

    //@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Drawing commands go here
        oval = new RectF(leftx,topy,rightx,bottomy);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, strt, arc, true, cPaint);
        while (i < 90)  {
            canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i)),f1,f2, tPaint);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
```

add the above below `setContentView`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
```

You need to set the layout using `setContentView` and then initialize views.

Note you can `findViewById` of the current view hierarchy set to the activity

Edit:

Example: This is an example. I don't see why it won't work if you do similar as below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".NewGame" 
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/prev_button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="stop_label" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/prev_button"
    android:text="start_label" />

  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/rl"
      android:layout_below="@+id/prev_button"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       >
  </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btn1;
    private EditText edt1, edt2, edt3, edt4 ,edt5, edt6;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyView mv = new MyView(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        layout.addView(mv);
    }
    class MyView extends View
    {

        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        }

    }
}
```

snapshot

[image]

Comment: it is now not giving any error but the contents of gameview are not being displayed on the screen

Comment: @user2586942 show us gameview.You should get NPE coz initialization of relative layout will fail.

Comment: sir gameview is the same as it was in my previous question that i posted.

Comment: it is basically to display an arc

Comment: then i don't see any reason why it won't work if your initialization succeeds show us your layout. in your case you initialize before `setContentView` which should give NPE

Comment: sir i have made the changes that u suggested and i have posted the layout file above

Comment: @user2586942 check the edit an example. It fills red. But it works if you do something similar it should work.

Comment: @user2586942 if you say you get error pls post the stack trace.

Comment: sir i have found the problem in my code.the gameview class was extending viewgroup and hence the problem.

Comment: @user2586942 this is why i asked you to post that code. post relevant bits of code otherwise it will lead to confusion. also if you say error or exception post the stacktrace and glad it you found out your mistake. if you extend viewgroup you should use dispatchdraw.

Comment: sir can you tell me how should i set the height and width of this view equal to that of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to inflate your view before trying to find your relative layout. Try :

```
RelativeLayout layout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameview=new GameView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

    //LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_new_game, gameview, true);

    layout.addView(gameview);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
```

you can't call `findViewById` before `setContentView`. Move

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
```

after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);`

Answer (score 0):

you didn't initialize `layout` in your code so First initialize `layout` after  `setContentView` then add view to your `layout`

```
RelativeLayout layout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_game);
    //Initialize game view
    GameView  gameview=new GameView(this);
    //initialize layout
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    //adding game view to layout
    layout.addView(gameview);
}
```

Edit:

initializing  like this before `setContentView`

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
```

is wrong approach you must initialize views only after `setContentView` like the above code